# Function of loss in R

Tags: r, minimum

I have function of loss given for a *k*-elements vector by the following formula:

[image: Formula]

Where *p* is a positive parameter. I have to write a function in R which returns the value of *u* which minimizes this function. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you know how to write a function? What inputs will your function take? Unless you show us what you have tried and where you are stuck we have no idea where to begin helping you, and instead it comes across like you just want someone to do your homework for you. [I'd suggest looking at the "Asking" section of the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for some tips on how best to use this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first define the function you want to minimize:

```
my_function <- function(u) {
    ...
}
```

Then you can call the `optim()` function:

```
result <- optim(starting_point_for_u, my_function, ...)
# parameter value minimizing the function
result$par
# minimal value of function
result$value
```

Comment: Well, it's not that simple (or I'm hopeless at programming) because number of components in my function depends on vector size (as formula states) and I don't really now how to transform vector to function.

Comment: Your function returns the sum of absolute values of x_i - u raised to the power of p, and you want to find the u that minimizes this quantity? If that's the case then it's that easy yes :) If that's not the case then you need to clarify your question and provide a code sample maybe.

Comment: Could you explain where you were stuck, maybe it will help somebody else. And don't say you're stupid, nobody is born with knowledge :)

Comment: It's part of my ordinal regression solution, and I wanted to have a function which minimalize that loss and returns this u. But in my mind it was function of x and p. How to minimize that? I forgot that I can define second function (of u) inside main function and then minimallize it.